# Closing UserControl In Wpf MDI Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, mdi

I am trying to create the mdi application in wpf using wpdmdi the external dll downloaded from http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/ .

1 I Have one main window with **menu** and **mdiconatiner** and code for **xaml** is below

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:mdi="clr-namespace:WPF.MDI;assembly=WPF.MDI"
        x:Class="Cheque.AccountSetup"
        Title="Main Window"
        MinHeight="480"
        MinWidth="800"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        WindowState="Maximized">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="31*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="473*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <telerik:RadMenu HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                             Height="28"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top"
                             FontSize="14">
                <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Setup">
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Account Set up"
                                         Click="AccountSetup_OnClick" />
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Cheque Design Template" />
                    <telerik:RadMenuSeparatorItem />
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Bank Name" />
                </telerik:RadMenuItem>
            </telerik:RadMenu>
            <mdi:MdiContainer Name="Container"
                              Theme="Generic"
                              Margin="0,28,0,0"
                              Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <mdi:MdiChild Name="ChildWindowContent"
                              WindowState="Maximized" />
            </mdi:MdiContainer>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

2 the code behind for opening the user control is

```
UserAccountSetup ase =new UserAccountSetup();
ChildWindowContent.Content = ase;
```

3 I have close button in userAccountSetup UserControl For closing usercontrol

```
AccountSetup mainWind = Application.Current.MainWindow as AccountSetup;
if (mainWind != null) mainWind.Container.Children.RemoveAt(0);
```

4 The usercontrol is closed on pressing exit button but when i again try to open the usercontrol from menu it does not open nor it gives any error .

please help me on this where i am wrong

i am using vs2013 and .net 4.5

Comment: coz you have removed ChildWindowContent while closing the usercontrol, try setting the ChildWindowContent.Content as null instead.

Comment: to set it to null you should write this code if (mainWind != null) mainWind.ChildWindowContent.Content = null; thanks @Nikita